# Django - How to create dependent selects

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My task is to implement a form in which the choice of the value of the second field depends on the value of the first field. (For example, if the value of the first field is Cars, then the second field should show sedan/SUV, etc., if the value of the first field is Commercial vehicles, then the second box should show truck/bus, etc.)

Code `models.py`:

```
class TypeTransport(models.Model):
    transport_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='kind of transport')


class TypeBodyTransport(models.Model):
    transport = models.ForeignKey(TypeTransport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
                                  verbose_name='kind of transport')
    body_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='transport body type')


class Advertisement(models.Model):
    transport = models.ForeignKey(TypeTransport, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                  verbose_name='kind of transport')
    body = models.ForeignKey(TypeBodyTransport, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                             verbose_name='transport body type ')
```

Code `forms.py`:

```
class CreateAdvertisementForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    transport = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TypeTransport.objects.all(), to_field_name="transport_name")
    body = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TypeBodyTransport.objects.filter(transport=transport),
                                  to_field_name="body_name")
    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('transport', 'body')
```

I thought it could be done with `filter(transport=transport)`, but this error is returned: `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x7f40d7af5ac0>.`

Can you please tell me how to implement the feature I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem  using the [django-smart-selects](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#chainedforeignkey-options) library. Additionally I can say that in the forms it is necessary to remove field which references to the `ModelChoiceField`, because it interferes with its `queryset` parameter. I'm still a beginner, so I didn't immediately guess that the problem was in chained selects (I edited the question).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```py
class CreateAdvertisementForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    transport = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TypeTransport.objects.all(), to_field_name="transport_name")
    body = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TypeBodyTransport.objects.filter(transport=transport.id),
                                  to_field_name="body_name")
    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('transport', 'body')
```

instead of `transport = transport`, try `transport = transport.id`

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work(( It's return error `AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'id'`